# Inno Setup: How to display components as list with radio buttons, not dropdown?

Tags: inno-setup

I am writing an installer for an application that prints and creates PDF files, and I want the user to be able to set a default page size for the output - either US Letter, Legal, or A4.

At the moment, my installer presents the list of options as a dropdown list in the Select Components page. Is there any way to present the list as a flat list with radio buttons? I've spent hours trying to do this, and can't find any obvious way. Here's the relevant code:

```
[Types]
Name: "SetUSLetterPaperSize"; Description: "Select US Letter paper size"; 
Name: "SetLegalPaperSize"; Description: "Select Legal paper size"; 
Name: "SetA4PaperSize"; Description: "Select A4 paper size"; 

[Components]
Name: "USLetterPaperSize"; Description: "Use US Letter paper size as default"; Types: SetUSLetterPaperSize; Flags: exclusive
Name: "LegalPaperSize"; Description: "Use Legal paper size as default"; Types: SetLegalPaperSize; Flags: exclusive
Name: "A4PaperSize"; Description: "Use A4 paper size as default"; Types: SetA4PaperSize; Flags: exclusive
```

I'll be grateful for any help, but I suspect I'll need to figure out some Pascal code, and haven't been able to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paper sizes are not Components. Use [Tasks](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection) with [`exclusive` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection&anchor=exclusive) instead.

To mark the default option, use [`unchecked` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection&anchor=unchecked) with all the other options.

```
[Tasks]
Name: SetUSLetterPaperSize; Description: "Select US Letter paper size"; Flags: exclusive
Name: SetLegalPaperSize; Description: "Select Legal paper size"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
Name: SetA4PaperSize; Description: "Select A4 paper size"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you - and that was staring me in the face all the time, but I didn't see it...